# Communicating VBA with Apps For Office 2013

Tags: javascript, vba, excel, office-2013, apps-for-office

Is there any way to share data **directly** between JavaScript running inside a Custom or Task Pane App for Office 2013 and VBA?

At the moment I'm handling this problem using an Office API binding to watch, read and write data to a worksheet cell. Example:

```
Office.context.document.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync("Example!A1:A1", Office.BindingType.Matrix, { id: "readFromCell" }, function (asyncResult) {
    Office.select("bindings#readFromCell").getDataAsync({ coercionType: "matrix" }, function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
            processData(asyncResult.value);
        }
    });
});
```

However, this approach is way too slow and messy. I'm searching for something closer to this:

VBA:

```
CommonStorage.setValue("example", "hello")
```

JavaScript:

```
var example = CommonStorage.getValue("example"); // Returns "hello"
```